# didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo not being called for UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to add a image upload feature to my iOS app. I have a function selectPicture() that gets called when user clicks on the upload button which then pops up an alert that allows the user to choose between camera and library.

```
func selectPicture() {
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Image Source", message: "Please choose your image source", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    let camera_action = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
        (_: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera) {
            print ("Camera Selected")
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
            imagePicker.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.coverVertical
            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    let photoLibrary_action = UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Library", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
        (_: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary) {
            print ("Photo Library Selected")
            
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
            imagePicker.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = self.navbarAttributes
            imagePicker.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
            imagePicker.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
            imagePicker.navigationBar.barTintColor = PING_ORANGE
            imagePicker.navigationController?.title = "Pick Image"
            imagePicker.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.coverVertical
            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    let cancel_action = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
        (_: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        print ("Cancel Selected")
    }
    alertController.addAction(camera_action)
    alertController.addAction(photoLibrary_action)
    alertController.addAction(cancel_action)
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    
}
```

Everything works fine till this point but when I select an image the delegate method is not being called.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any], editingInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]!) {
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    print("Image Print")
    print(image)
    if image != nil {
        print ("INSIDE IMAGE DID FINISH PICKING")
        dismiss(animated: false) {
            self.uploadProfileImage(image: image!)
        }
        
    } else {
        dismiss(animated: false) {
            
        }
    }
}
```

I'm new to swift so I might be missing something. Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed this by using:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                           didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        dismiss(animated: false) {
            self.uploadProfileImage(image: image)
   
        }
    }
    else {
        dismiss(animated: false) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your Swift and Xcode versions? You should update your Xcode to the latest version

Comment: I have the latest xcode but thw swift version is old. This project was on hold for long so its just a temporary app. Im doing a new one on react native.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using an old code. Your [method signature](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontrollerdelegate/1619126-imagepickercontroller) is wrong. It should be:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    if let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
        print("Image Print")
        print(image)
        dismiss(animated: false) {
            self.uploadProfileImage(image: image)
        }
    } else {
        dismiss(animated: false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to move `let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()` to outside the scope of the function to prevent it from getting deallocated